# How to center a image next to an input field using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to center a image next to an input field although when attempting to do so with `vertical-align: bottom;` nothing happens and my image is not centered where I want it to be.

I have tried to use `position:relative` and then move my image using top,bottom etc but I want to do it in a way that uses flexbox.

How would I go about doing this and what divs would I have to change to get the layout I want.

[Layout I am trying to achieve:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKFOh.png)

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ehroyfn6/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Inputs</h1>
    <p class="spacing">multiple inputs...</p>
    <div class="searchinput">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="google-input" placeholder="Google search...">
        <img src="logos/google.png" alt="youtube" class="logos">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logos{
    width: 90px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 90vh;  
}

.searchinput {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


input {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the direct parent of the items that you want to have flex properties to have the `display:flex` property.  So in your case it would be the `.searchinput`.  So your `.searchinput` css should be the following:

```
.searchinput {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

So here is a snippet of the whole thing:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.logos{
    width: 90px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 90vh;  
}

.searchinput {
    margin-top: 20px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}


input {
    padding: 20px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Inputs</h1>
    <p class="spacing">multiple inputs...</p>
    <div class="searchinput">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="google-input" placeholder="Google search...">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dpkbGqu.png" alt="youtube" class="logos">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks although if I remove the `margin-top` and just have `display:flex;
& align-items: center;` there is a weird gap how do I fix this? https://i.imgur.com/LLSbF48.png

Comment: it looks like your image is taller than your input so flex box is taking in consideration the height of your image and centering the input and the image.  if you inspect the image in chrome dev tools you can see that your image is 67px tall so your .searchinput that is containing the image is going to be 67px tall and yoiur input isn't this tall so flexbox is centering the two items and the white space you see is the extra height of the image.  I hope that makes sense.